# How to upload file via cURL in kohana 3?

Tags: file-upload, curl, kohana-3

I try

```
$request = Request::factory($url)->method(Request::POST)->post('xml', '@' . $filepath);
echo $request->execute();
```

but print_r($_FILES); in destination script returns empty array.

Version of Kohana is 3.2.0 stable

What I want is a simple analog of

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => '@' . $filepath));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$request_url = 'your_url_here';
        $post_params['name'] = urlencode('Test User');
        $post_params['file'] = ‘@’.'demo/testfile.txt’;
        $post_params['submit'] = urlencode('submit');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's possible to do that with Kohana 3.3 using Request#files() method.

Edit: actually, it's not part of official release, so before 3.4 you probably won't be able to do it.